# android, dispose intent after handling it?

Tags: android, android-intent

I get intent for push or custom scheme in A activity.

I'm handling them in `onResume`.

It seems the intents are not disposed unless explicitly told.
I start an activity for intents, and when I close the started activity, it keeps restarted (I suspect this is due to the living intents)
How should I dispose them?

Are there better way of handling for example, push intent?
(without the need to disposing them?)

--- edit

I think my problem is due to the way I handle push, (or scheme)

`GcmIntentService` creates notification which would start a `MainActivity`
`MainActivity` then look at args and starts `appropriate activities`.

I guess the more conventional way is to go from `GcmIntentService` to `appropriate activities` directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this inside onCreate() method of your MainActivity.java :

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
final Intent launchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

If the activity is already created, rather put this inside onStart() method.

Comment: what if my activity is already created, when user clicks push notification. onCreate won't be called, no?

Comment: onStart, and onResume would have the same problem of reusing intent in my case I think? see my edited question please